# LaTeX document without \documentclass

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

I need to create a really simple document template for other people to fill in and compile (e.g., they need to provide a name and email address). I could distribute it as a `.cls` file and a template `.tex` file, but I think it might be easier to just distribute it as a single file.

It appears that one can compile a document without a `\documentclass` without any warnings. For example, despite not having a `\documentclass` line, the following is a complete MWE:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

Where the entire "class" is `\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}`. What are the drawbacks of defining the entire "class" within the `.tex` file and not using a `\documentclass` line?

**EDIT**

To add a little more about what I am doing. I created a custom class that was not based on any other class. I then took David Carlisle idea

and changed

```
\documentclass{myclass}
```

to

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
%  your definitions
\makeatother
```

but this caused conflicts of things that were defined in both `myclass` and the `article` class. It probably would have been better to use the `minimal` class, but I realized that I didn't need the `\documentclass{article}` before I thought about the `minimal` class.

Comment: For one, inability to use `\usepackage`.

Comment: I thought `\documentclass` was mandatory :P

Comment: It might not be good LaTeX style, but Daniel's code actually works ;)

Comment: Me too, which is why I asked.

Comment: texdoc source2e and search for `\normalsize` is used to produce an error, so if you define it you can run a classless document.

Comment: Of course, your definitions from your class file must be _redefinitions_ in the `\makeatletter`…`\makeatother` block, at least the ones, where you get conflicts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at `minimal.cls` you will see it does a bit more than just set the normal font size:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{minimal}[2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class]

\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}

\pagenumbering{arabic}  % but no page numbers are printed because:
\pagestyle{empty}       % this is actually already in the kernel
```

In particular things are likely to go very wrong if you don't set `\textheight` and `\textwidth`.

However there is no advantage to not using a real class such as `article` and many disadvantages.

If you just want to distribute a single template file and no class file use a format like

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter

 %  your definitions

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

---

Looking at the edited question, if your custom code *does* set up everything then you could just stick it at the top as you said, the problems with `minimal` then don't apply. Perhaps better though would be to use a form

```
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
% your definitions
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

That way the file can easily be switched between assuming `myclass` is already installed and including it inline. Such ad-hoc distribution of local class and package files was one of the main motivations for adding `filecontents` to LaTeX2e.

Comment: I tried exactly this before asking. The problem I ran into was conflicts with the `article` class and my class defining the same macros. I would have needed to change many `\newcommand`'s to `\renewcommand`'s. I therefore think the `minimal` class is probably better in this situation.

Comment: No, I promise you, it isn't. `minimal` is the smallest class I could make that would let you test the new (at the time) package loading mechanism but if you use it for actual documents things will go wrong. Math isn't set up, font size commands are not set up, figures/tables are not set up, more or less anything that any package that you load expects has not been set up.

Comment: see edited answer.

Comment: `If you look at mininmal.cls`... Should be `minimal`.

Answer (score 9):

> I need to create a really simple document template for other people to
>   fill in and compile.

I am not sure what you after, as to why the user needs to compile. The minimal check that LaTeX does to see if a class is defined is to produce an error if `\normalsize` has not been redefined see `source2e`, `ltfntcmd.dtx`.

If you really want to go minimalistic go pure `TeX`.

```
 J. Smith, myemail@goom.com
 \bye
```

Answer (score 3):

As I've tested some quite basic environments that came in my mind, there is pretty much no functionality at all.
All environments and commands that are not included in plain TeX won't work. So you have no possibilities to produce tables or lists with LaTeX. If this works for your special purpose, it's fine.

As you've mentioned, there is not even an `\usepackage` available, one could not do very much. It's just up to you if the functionallity you get by this very reduced code is working.

Maybe you try some pretty small document classes like `minimal` or `standalone`. With your code it's just one extra line, to load it, but you earn much more functionallity

Comment: I thought macros like `\renewcommand` were part of LaTeX and not plain TeX?

Comment: Daniel, you are right. But some plain TeX stuff works, if you try e.g. `$\alpha$` ;-)

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk That isn't plain TeX stuff, it is LaTeX stuff that has similar name/definition to the definition in plain. `\alpha` is defined in LaTeX by `\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{letters}{"0B}` and in plain by `\mathchardef\alpha="010B` Actually with the default latex font setup these come to the same thing, but the actual sources of plain tex are not used at all in latex.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, I didn't realize that yet, again I've learned something.