# Am I using LaTex2e?

Tags: versions

I am about to prepare a paper for a conference. In the template that given to me from the conference owner says " Only if you use `\LaTeXe{}` can hyperlinks be generated in the online version of your manuscript" Here is the page: http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0

How can I check what version of latex I am using?  And how can I check this hyperlink thing in my current work?

windows 8, texmaker 4.3, miktex 2.9

Comment: You should give us more information. Unless you use `plain TeX` or `ConTeXt` I would say you are applying `LateX2e` or even the features of the upcoming `LaTeX3`

Comment: `tex --version`. anything past 1995 or so is more than likely LaTeX2e.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Howso LaTeX3? While some ideas of LaTeX3 exist implemented for 2e, 3 has yet to be released.  Lots to do :)

Comment: I saw this now: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13548/68836 if it is true then I think there is nothing to worry about. right?

Comment: @WhoCares correct.

Comment: @SeanAllred thank you. and thank you all. topic is locked :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: In the sense of `expl3` ;-)

Comment: To get the version programmatically: [tex core - Detecting which version of the LaTeX format is in use - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26178/detecting-which-version-of-the-latex-format-is-in-use)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using a system that does not give an error if the first line of your document is

```
\documentclass{...}
```

then it is LaTeX2e.

It also advertises this on the terminal and in the log at the start of every job with a line like

```
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
```

Comment: +1 for a clever test -- your best bet is to always just ask the system :)

Comment: I also wonder why it doesn't include `LaTeX2e` in the banner.  Is there no way for pdfTeX to reliably and consistently determine the version of the format it's called with?

Comment: you mean what? This? `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
`

Comment: @SeanAllred That banner is put out before the format is read, if you use `latex &plain` you see the same thing. `\everyjob` is about the first place the message could be, and that's where it is

Comment: @SeanAllred: just wondering whether there is anyone but Emacs users who would use the phrasing "ask the system" ;-)

Comment: @mbork is there anyone but emacs users?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: of course, there are the evil Vim users, and then a lot of children playing with toys and calling them "text editors". ;-)

Answer (score 7):

If your document's first main instruction is

```
\documentclass...
```

you're using LaTeX2e.

If it's

```
\documentstyle...
```

you're using LaTeX 2.09 either directly (if your TeX distribution is truly prehistoric, ie 1994 or earlier) or in compatibility mode (for any TeX distribution since 1995).

If the first main instruction is neither of the above, you're not running LaTeX.

Comment: "Main instruction" is rather vague.  Though likely true in virtually all LaTeX2e documents, you could easily have `\def`s, `\newif`s, `\begin{filecontents}`, `\RequirePackage{snapshot}`, etc., etc. before `\documentclass`.  It might not be clear to everyone that these are not a "first main instruction".  (That is to say, I know that *you* know this..!)

Comment: @jon -- Thanks. I deliberately didn't specify what constitutes a "main instruction". If a reader doesn't know what this term means in the context of a LaTeX document, the whole posting probably doesn't make sense to begin with. Anyway, you've done a splendid job mentioning some non-main instructions, so there's nothing more for me to add. :-)

Comment: You can have a LaTeX2e document without `\documentclass`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94724/latex-document-without-documentclass

Comment: @StrongBad - I suppose I was using a working definition of "LaTeX document" that includes, as one of its purposes, the desire to actually get something real typeset. Put differently, I'm not particularly concerned with demonstration projects that abuse LaTeX (the executable) for purposes LaTeX (the format) is absolutely not designed for. While such demonstration projects may indeed compile successfully, i.e., without generating error messages, I'd say that little is lost by *not* considering them to be real LaTeX documents.